# How to run multiple functions in parallel using python script

Tags: python, multithreading

We have 7 functions which we have to run parallel using python script ,we have tried using multiprocessor and Process api of python but still the functions are running one by one ,I have created one method and with multiple functional block and i tried with multiple method but that also didnt work..

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

This will run one by one:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def say_hello(name='world'):
    print "Hello, %s" % name

p = Process(target=say_hello)
p.start()
p.join()
p2 = Process(target=say_hello)
p2.start()
p2.join()
```

This will run it in parallel:

```
p = Process(target=say_hello)
p.start()
p2 = Process(target=say_hello)
p2.start()
p.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: I have a method prod(x) and have multiple if loops(x value equals to 1 to 7) and tried calling the way u told.

p = Process(target=prod(1))
p.start()
p2 = Process(target=prod(2))
p2.start()
p.join()
p2.join() adn so on also tried the following code

processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=prod(x)) for x in range(0, 8)]
[process.start() for process in processes]
[process.join() for process in processes]